# Reject email and force the sender to switch MX records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mx-record

I am setting up a mail server solution.

I want to apply the scenario like this:

- The **domain** used is configured with **2 MX records** (one with **priority 1** - *my server* and one with **10** - *a third party STMP server*)
- I want the sender to keep using MX record with **priority 10** until I have added that **domain** to my mail server for it to accept incoming mail.

How can I **reject** the **incoming mail** when it is not accepted by my mail server?

More specifically, which **kind of error** I need to return if I want the sender to **switch MX records**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should do this! The correct way is:

1. First configure the primary MX to accept mail for the domain.
2. Only after that you can add the MX record.

All the temporary error codes (`4yz` *Transient Negative Completion reply*) tells to try again later, not to try with another MX. From [RFC 5321, 4.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2.5): Reply Codes after DATA and the Subsequent `<CRLF>.<CRLF>`:

> When an SMTP server returns a temporary error status (`4yz`) code after
> the `DATA` command is completed with `<CRLF>.<CRLF>`, it MUST NOT make a
> subsequent attempt to deliver that message.  The SMTP client retains
> responsibility for the delivery of that message and may either return
> it to the user or requeue it for a subsequent attempt (see    [Section
> 4.5.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.4.1)).

Therefore, there's no suitable response code for this. The backup MX records are only used if a server with a lower value of the priority isn't reachable. (See [RFC 5321, 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5.1) for details.)

---

An addition based on the comments:

**You shouldn't use the MX records for domain verification,** but you could use `TXT` records. That's how e.g. both [Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/add-domain?view=o365-worldwide) and [G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60216?hl=en) does this before you can configure their email services.

Comment: So that means if my primary server is up, there's no way for the sender to try other MX records right?

Comment: Why first create a problem and then try to solve it, when you could do this the standard way, not having the problem at all?

Comment: Actually I am working on a mail server that others will point their DNS to mine. (and my mail server manage the accepted domains). However I cannot guarantee that they will correctly configured DNS or register legitimate domains. The 1st priority MX is my mail server, the 10th priority MX is 3rd party mail server. Before everything is setup right, I want their mails to 3rd party server. That is all my purpose